# what is the difference between these two lines? with integer in different spots

Tags: c++

What is the difference between having

```
main(int x){
}
```

from

```
main(){
int x;
}
```

?

Comment: This question doesn't really make any sense. Under what circumstances would you be comparing these two completely different things?

Comment: This is something covered in any C++ book/tutorial, even mediocre ones. Why would you need to ask that here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declares a function `main` that accepts an integer parameter `x`:

```
main(int x){
}
```

This declares a function `main` that does not accept any parameters, then declares an integer `x` within that function's scope:

```
main(){
    int x;
}
```

This is a fairly basic distinction, making this question rather off-topic for this site. You should consider finding a good tutorial or one of the learn-to-program sites out there to walk you through this kind of stuff. Searching Google or your preferred search engine for `c++ tutorial`, `learn to program c++`, or something similar should turn up lots of resources to get you started.